# Creating a PDF that is invalidated if edited?

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly. I need to be able to create a PDF file from C# that would somehow become 'invalid' if it is edited. We're creating a transcript for a university and want to ensure that what is presented to someone is an unaltered pdf.

Ideally a person couldn't even open the pdf if it's been altered or there would be some sort of VOID watermark if it had been altered from its original state.

Can iText do anything like this? Or is there another tool that might fit the bill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called cryptographic signing, it verifies that the document is intact since signed and who the signer is. In any case PDF has options for allowing edit, print etc signing and so forth. See for example [signing in acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/acrobat/pdfs/adobe-acrobat-xi-esign-pdf-file-tutorial-ue.pdf). See your PDF generation modules feature list for more appropriate answers.

However while its technically possible to notice that the document has been altered. That does not mean the user can not remake the document without signing (like printing to another PDF). The new PDF then does not have a signature and it can be altered as much as the user likes.

This makes this a social problem that can not be solved easily. See as long as the general public is not aware of how to verify the document technically. And that really all documents are verifiable. it will not help they can still fraud as much as they like. So this only solves the problem for those users that are aware of the problem.

Comment: To elaborate on @joojaa's post, if you can control and train the group that needs to know if a document has been altered then PDF signing should work for you. Most PDF renderers should immediately alert if they detect an invalid signature which will happen if even a single byte of the document gets changed. Check out the official iText book as well as this post from the author: http://lowagie.com/node/371

Comment: Thanks Chris. The book can now be downloaded directly here: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and the C# port of most of the examples is available here: sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/